# Given y'=f(x,y) why is it that dy/dx = M(x,y)/-N(x,y)?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

In the book Schaum's Outline Series Differential Equations, the second chapter explains that a differential equation of the form $$y'=f(x,y) $$ can be written as $$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{M(x,y)}{-N(x,y)} $$ which this is used to derive what they explain as a differential form. $$ M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy = 0 $$ I am very confused as to where this notion of how f(x,y) can be written as the quotient of the two functions  comes from. I would like to know how we derived this and understand it. I am also worried that the Schaum's Outline Series book will lack further information on the subject, I don't understand where this has come from.

Comment: In the most simple case, set $N(x,y)=-1$, then $M(x,y)=f(x,y)$. If you have the equation given as fraction, you can use that structure to assign $M$ and $N$.

Comment: @LutzL I understand that part but where does this notion come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at this story backwards. The aim of using the exact DE form is to find some function $F$ called a *first integral* so that all solutions lie on level curves of $F$. This is also called an implicit solution.

Now if $F(x,y(x))=c$, then 
$$\partial_xF(x,y)+\partial_yF(x,y)\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
and 
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\partial_xF(x,y)}{\partial_yF(x,y)}.
$$
Think of the exact form
$$
\partial_xF(x,y)dx+\partial_yF(x,y)dy=0
$$
as nothing more than a fancy form of writing the vector $(\partial_xF(x,y),\partial_yF(x,y))$.

Now what you want to do is construct backwards the function $F$ by guessing its partial derivatives $(M,N)$ from the equation, and if they don't integrate, enhancing the guess more or less systematically using the diverse *integrating factor* constructions so that $\phi\cdot(M,N)$ is integrable.

There is some freedom in this, if $F$ is a first integral then also all compositions $h\circ F$ with a scalar (monotonous, differentiable) function are also (equivalent) first integrals.